# Restoring an AWS Aurora cluster from a snapshot using the same cluster identifier using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, snapshot, database-restore

Scenario:

- An AWS Aurora (Postgres) cluster is currently running, but something is wrong with it.
- To solve this issue, I want to restore a cluster snapshot created some days earlier and reset to that point in time.
- I use CDK for my infrastructure and restore the cluster using the `DatabaseClusterFromSnapshot` class.

**Problem**: the old cluster and new cluster must carry the exact same cluster identifier. Because AWS deletes the old cluster only after the new cluster is created, this results in a naming conflict.

Is there any feasible way to reach my goal of having the new cluster carrying the exact same name? On our production environment, there is deletion protection so I cannot create a custom resource to delete the cluster before the new one is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Manually rename `my_cluster` to `my_cluster_old`. Follow [this AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RenameInstance.html) (see caveats about read replicas). The commands for clusters may be somewhat different (e.g., [modify-db-cluster](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-cluster.html)).
2. Restore the snapshot to `my_cluster`.
3. Delete `my_cluster_old`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the best option I have. Only side note is that because we are dealing with deletion protection on production, we'll have to think about a solution to remove the old cluster.